# Asihttprequest is manage redirected url automaically?

Tags: ios, url, asihttprequest

Our old ios projects web service address will be redirect and we used asihttprequest in that project.

Is Asihttprequest manage redirected url automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## yes

the framework will call:
`- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request willRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)newURL{`

the original request will proceed.
(if you need you can cancel the old one and open a new one)